# How to add space/padding between rectangles in custom painter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a custom painter class in which is drawing rectangles with data got from the sample list. Now it draws without space in between.
How can I add spacing or padding between them?

Here is the code

```
class RectPath extends CustomPainter {
  final List<double> sample;

  RectPath(this.sample);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()..color = Colors.lightGreen;
    for (var i in sample) {
      canvas.drawRect(
          Rect.fromCenter(
              center: Offset(sample.indexOf(i) + 0.0, 25.0), width: 15, height: i * 0.8),
          paint);
      
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than adding 0.0 to sample list's index just multiply it's index with width of your bar and gap you want between

in your case bar width is 15 and I want gap of 5 so I'll do index*15+5 as shown below

```
  class RectPath extends CustomPainter {
  final List<double> sample;

  RectPath(this.sample);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()..color = Colors.lightGreen;
    for (var i in sample) {
      canvas.drawRect(
          Rect.fromCenter(
              center: Offset(sample.indexOf(i) * 15+5, 25.0), width: 15, height: i * 0.8),
          paint);
      
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```